# Modify UserDetailsService of Pentaho

Tags: spring-security

I need receive two string parameters  in loadUserByUsername method. I do not want to use spring security authentication, for this a have my own implementation that needs password too (It´s a integration system).

Is it possible create another method with the same name loadUserByUsername(String username, String password) in the same class, and call that method instead another one ?

Comment: Why do you need it? It looks like you want authenticate a user and you  use wrong SpringSecurity class to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand this requirement but `UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(String)` is just fine. At the time this method is invoked the user is already authenticated and hence the password is not needed anymore. So, if you need a password at that point there's a fair chance you're doing something wrong.

If you want to implement your own authentication mechanism based on username & password you need to provide your own `AuthenticationProvider`.

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <security:authentication-provider ref="yourProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="yourProvider" class="package.yourProviderClass">
  <!-- I suppose you need this, too -->
  <property name="userDetailsService" ref="yourUserDetailsService" />
</bean>
```

Have a look at the existing implementations and find the one that most closely offers what you need.

[image]

Comment: I'll try your sugestion: create my own AuthenticationProvider. This looks like the better way. Thanks